# css grid with images the first image 50% width and all the others 25%

Tags: css

I want to make a grid with images. All images are have the same dimensions. The first will be 50% width and all the others 25%. I wrote the following code. In most resolutions is OK, but when i resize the window in some cases the first image it brokes, and is not 50%.

```
<img src="1.jpg" class="img1" />
<img src="1.jpg" class="img2" />
<img src="1.jpg" class="img2" />
<img src="1.jpg" class="img2" />
<img src="1.jpg" class="img2" />
<img src="1.jpg" class="img2" />
<img src="1.jpg" class="img2" />
<img src="1.jpg" class="img2" />
<img src="1.jpg" class="img2" />
<img src="1.jpg" class="img2" />

.img1
{
    width:50%;
    float:left;
}

.img2
{
    width:25%;
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: Could you create a jsfiddle? Makes it much easier for us.

Comment: Here it is. Try to resize the width box to the result

https://jsfiddle.net/j1bdy04a/

Comment: I think you forgot the link haha

Comment: In which scenario it is not of the size you expected?

Comment: just resize the result box by the horizontal width to see what happens

Answer (score 0):

I don't seem to replicate the first image braking. But this might be a more robust solution

css

```
img {
    width:25%;
    float:left;
}

img:first-child {
  width:50%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qyos51jj/

Comment: It has the same problem again. Just resize horizontal the result box. It seems that is not always 50% the first image, or 25% all the others in some cases

Answer (score 0):

This is an infamous **problem about fluid images**.

Let's assume you have an image 800px wide and 450px high. Your image can easily have a width of 400px and a height of 225px, right? There will be no half pixels; everything will be in order. How about a width of 200px? What will be the height then?

Well, fluid images will always encounter a pixel width where **their height will have a decimal value**. The browser will evaluate it to a nearest integer and the aspect ratio will be broken. So, if your layout requires a no-margin image tiling or any other similar placement, you are in trouble.

However, if you know the aspect ratio of the images and if they will be the same, **there is a fix for this**. It may not be the perfect fix, but will solve many cases, probably including yours. Take a look at the following code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="img1"><img src="http://archontikomanias.gr/files/files/slider/1.jpg" /></div>
<div class="img2"><img src="http://archontikomanias.gr/files/files/slider/1.jpg" /></div>
<div class="img2"><img src="http://archontikomanias.gr/files/files/slider/1.jpg" /></div>
<div class="img2"><img src="http://archontikomanias.gr/files/files/slider/1.jpg" /></div>
<div class="img2"><img src="http://archontikomanias.gr/files/files/slider/1.jpg" /></div>
<div class="img2"><img src="http://archontikomanias.gr/files/files/slider/1.jpg" /></div>
<div class="img2"><img src="http://archontikomanias.gr/files/files/slider/1.jpg" /></div>
<div class="img2"><img src="http://archontikomanias.gr/files/files/slider/1.jpg" /></div>
<div class="img2"><img src="http://archontikomanias.gr/files/files/slider/1.jpg" /></div>
<div class="img2"><img src="http://archontikomanias.gr/files/files/slider/1.jpg" /></div>
<div class="img2"><img src="http://archontikomanias.gr/files/files/slider/1.jpg" /></div>
<div class="img2"><img src="http://archontikomanias.gr/files/files/slider/1.jpg" /></div>
<div class="img2"><img src="http://archontikomanias.gr/files/files/slider/1.jpg" /></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.img1,
.img2 {
  float:left;
  height:0
}
.img1 {
  width:50%;
  padding:0 0 32.5%
}

.img2 {
  width:25%;
  padding:0 0 16.75%
}

.img1>img,
.img2>img {
  width:100%;
  height:auto
}
```

We followed the following steps here:

1. Place the `img` elements inside `div` elements
2. Assign the classes with floats and the size properties to the `div` elements
3. Define the height of the `div` elemenst as 0 (zero)
4. Put paddings on the `div` elements according to the aspect ratios (may require fine-tuning)

You may find how it works here: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eyzx424y/4/)